# Iterate nested array to get the same index value from all objects at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a nested array like following:

```
[
  myfield: {value1,value2},
  myotherfield: {value1,value2}
]
```

If i have the next scenario

```
[
  myfield: {"A","B"},
  myotherfield: {"C","D"}
]
```

How can i iterate the arrays to get the value1 of both fields at the same time? In this case i need to get A & C on the first iteration and B & D on the second iteration.

Comment: You have your `[]` and `{}` backwards...

Comment: You can't. Reading from a bidimensional object has `O(n^2)` time complexity. So you need `2` loops. Also, check the comment above.

Comment: @AngelPolitis That's only needed if you want all combinations. If you just want corresponding elements, a single loop is fine.

Comment: That's the case only when the keys are hardcoded into the code. In the general case, for an object with `m` keys, each set to an array of `n` elements, a total of `mn` iterations are needed.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  myfield: ["A","B"],
  myotherfield: ["C","D"]
};

data.myfield.forEach((fieldA, index) => {
    const fieldB = data.myotherfield[index];
  console.log(fieldA, fieldB);
})
```

- Note1: Use this if both entries have the same length.
- Note2: If both entries can have a different length then you need to check what of the two has the highest length while making the other entries return null.

Comment: This is exactly what i need, both entries will always have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = A.map((data_A, index) => {
    const data_B = B[index]

    console.log("data", data_A, data_B )
})
```